# Weird behaviour of a pre_hook inside a config block in a dbt model

Tags: google-bigquery, macros, jinja2, dbt, dbt-cloud

I would like to run a DELETE statement before the execution of a model. The model is called **ga_events** and the DELETE statement should be based on another model called **stg_events_inc**. There fore I've created a macro:

```
{%- macro get_delete_statement(table, stg_table) -%}
    DELETE FROM {{ table }} WHERE event_date BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(event_date) FROM {{ stg_table }}) AND (SELECT MAX(event_date) FROM {{ stg_table }});
{%- endmacro -%}
```

I’m calling the macro in the **ga_events** model inside the config block, like so:

```
{{
    config(
        materialized = 'incremental',
        pre_hook = get_delete_statement(this, ref('stg_events_inc')),
        on_schema_change = 'fail'
    )
}}
```

The final compilated DELETE statement looks like this:

```
DELETE FROM `project`.`schema`.`ga_events` WHERE event_date BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(event_date) FROM `project`.`schema`.`ga_events`) AND (SELECT MAX(event_date) FROM `project`.`schema`.`ga_events`);
```

No matter what reference to a model I put into the the macro arguments, it always references the model itself (**ga_events**). I just do not understand this kind of behaviour. However, if this is not in the config block it works normally.

The same applies for the sql_header config parameter.